# KeyStore and TrustStore load failed - Private key must be accompanied by certificate chain

Tags: java, ssl, keystore

I have created a self signed certificate using the following command:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -alias test-api -keystore test-api.p12 -storepass password -validity 3650 -keysize 2048 -storetype pkcs12
```

I then imported this keystore into new truststore:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias test-api-2018 -file test.crt -keystore trusted-keystore.p12 -storetype pkcs12
```

In Java, creating a custom SSL store provider (`org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.SslStoreProvider`). As a part of it,  loaded keystore and truststore using the following Java code:

```
try {

        try (final InputStream keyStoreStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(keyStoreEncoded))) {

            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_TYPE_PKCS12);

            LOGGER.info("Loading a KeyStore object based on the decoded value.");

            keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, serverSslKeyPassword.toCharArray());
        }

        ....    
            trustStore.load(trustStoreStream, serverSslTrustStorePassword.toCharArray());
        }
```

Created custom implementation of `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` and set SSL Provider:

```
public void customize(final ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer configurableEmbeddedServletContainer) {
    configurableEmbeddedServletContainer.setSslStoreProvider(awsSslStoreProvider);
}
```

Application fails to start because of the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Private key must be accompanied by certificate chain
at java.security.KeyStore.setKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:1136)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:253)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114)
... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use the truststore as a keystore. Incomplete information deters further speculation.

Comment: Created keystore, applied Base64 encoding, then exported certificate from keystore (test.crt). Created a truststore that trusts test.crt. In Java, creating a custom SSL Store Provider (`org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.SslStoreProvider`), loading keystore and truststore.

Comment: What you *think* you did isn't relevant. If you were thinking correctly, and the code did what you thought it did, you wouldn't have a problem and you wouldn't be asking this question. Show the code that supposedly implements what you thought you did.

Comment: "I then imported this keystore into new truststore:": no you didn't. You imported a *certificate file* into the new truststore, with `keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias test-api-2018 -file test.crt ...`.

Answer (score 46):

The problem occurs when the security config in the `application.properties` file isn't configured properly. This causes the certificate chain to break.

In my case I used

```
 server.ssl.key-password=123456789
```

instead of

```
server.ssl.key-store-password=123456789
```

Comment: You may have saved my life!

Comment: Thanks. This post ended a 2+ hour search.

Comment: I tried various solution and this simple change saved my day too. Thank you in the name of everyone.

Answer (score 2):

This also happens when using BouncyCastle as PKCS12 key store provider and the key alias is using incorrect upper case.

E.g. (incorrect):

```
server.ssl.key-alias=17B2E92E5694C7AE11A65C4A4EBFC75558399E05
```

instead (correct):

```
server.ssl.key-alias=17b2e92e5694c7ae11a65c4a4ebfc75558399e05
```

The strange thing about this error is that the key is found, so obviously is not case sensitive, but the check for `ks.getCertificateChain(keyAlias)` is.

Comment: I had a very nasty bug that was due to the alias name being case sensitive, it was working fine with tomcat yet not with undertow, thanks !